# In Codename One, how do I build a separator component?

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to have a Codename One component equivalent to the JSeparator in Swing.  Any idea how I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to separate two elements just add any component and define a style with the look you would like the component to have. E.g. if you do something like this:

```
Label l = new Label(" ");
l.setUIID("Separator");
```

Then in the designer just style the Separator UIID appropriately to represent the look you want. Notice I used the space character in the label since there is a special case where blank labels are hidden.

Comment: Shai, can you explain in a bit more detail? I'm yet to find a way in the designer to create a style that results in a simple line separator with thickness of about 1mm. What steps do I need to follow to get that? The only solution I found so far is in the [Facebook Demo](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-demos/blob/master/FacebookDemo/src/com/codename1/fbdemo/FBDemo.java#L73) where the line is painted under a label. Is there an equivalent using the designer?

Comment: Drag a Label into place and give it the string `" "` then set its UIID to "Separator". In the theme add "Separator" and select an image representing a line of your desired thickness in the background section. Select one of the "TILE_HORIZONTAL_* background behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification though this looks like a workaround for something that should be simple. It's also not a flexible solution. For example, if I want to change the color of the line, I'll need to create another image... I would expect a separator to be a standard component with options to set thickness, color, etc. Please consider adding that in the new GUI builder. And spacers/fillers too ;). It's really a pain to get UIs that scale well on different device sizes. The most flexible layout is the table layout but it doesn't quite work as one would expect for adding fillers/spacers.

Comment: Instead of using an image you can also go to the colors section, set the bg transparency to 255 and set the color. Then define the exact size thru the padding arguments. We can add it as a specific component but I'm not sure if the UX will be much better. The new GUI builder was supposed to launch with a new layout manager too but we scraped that as the project dragged on without reaching completion. We'll return to that when the time is right.